# Trying to get a .xml file with vb.net, converting from CURL/PHP

Tags: xml, vb.net, curl

Problem:
  I don't know how to 'convert' a cURL PHP command to vb.net, so I can fetch a .xml file.
  I've been looking around for hours on the internet and found things as the webclient class and other classes. But all the cases I found had different cURL params so I couldn't figure out how to adapt the code ,that was suggested, to my cURL params.

cURL:

> > `cURL -u user:password -d http://website/API/search.xml?q=Value`

It needs validation to allow searching the databases the website has.

I know how to GET something using HttpWebRequest and a URL, but then it ofcourse gives the error that the request isn't validated (error 401 if that's useful information)

Since all the other posts I found had cURL commands similar to this:

> > `curl -X POST -i -H "Accept: application/json" -u someusername:somepassword "https://domain.com/xyz/api/user" -d 'firstName=john&lastName=smith&ssn=111223333&currentAddress=1 Main ST&currentCity=somecity&currentState=WA&currentZip=99999'`

I wasn't able to adept the given code.

I hope someone can help me a bit with this, since I've no idea on how to include these parameters into the GET command for vb.net (in this case more the HttpWebRequest)

Thanks In Advance! Syths.

Comment: I have no idea about vb.net, but this use of curl -u will use those credentials with HTTP Basic authentication and it is the lack of that header that makes the server respond with 401...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you need some specific params, or is your first example what you're trying for?

[My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ack30t8y(v=vs.90).aspx)

```
    My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile("http://website/API/search.xml?q=value", _
        "%localpath%/search.xml", "username", "password")
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.

I used the code you supplied to download the file I wanted and it worked like a charm.

Thanks!